# viewbag contains sorted list but not reflected in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting, razor

In my view(.cshtml) i am getting viewbag with list elements.and this list elements are already sorted from where it comes from(controller).During runtime i put break point and i can see viewbag contains sorted list elements in (@foreach (var item in ViewBag.bulk)). but problem is, it is not showing up sorted in the browser instead it shows unsorted order. 
here is my razor code

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.bulk)
{
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/pics/"+@item.itemID+".jpg")" alt="@item.Name" title="@item.title"></a>
}
```

what will be the reason?
i am using mvc5, entity framework and linq

Comment: Could you also post the code where you sort the list?

Comment: List<Customer> customer = new List<Customer>();
customer = (from cust in db.customers_T where flag=1 orderby cust.Title
                        
                                       select new Customer()
                                       {
                                           CustID = cust.custID,
                                           Title = cust.Title,
                                           
                                       }).ToList();
                        
                        ViewBag.bulk = customer;

Comment: let me remind u i get this in sorted even in view. i can see that elements in sorted order

Answer (score 1):

The loop will  not work  You have  to type cast the list first

```
foreach (var image in ((List<Class>)ViewBag.bulk))
```